# Discord Python Rewrite - Reaction Help (Cog)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a help that relies on reactions, I got this code

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

class Helptest(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def helpreee(self, ctx):

        await ctx.message.delete()

        msg = await ctx.send("Eh idk just react")

        await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
        await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

        try:

            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)

            if reaction.emoji == '➡️':

                await ctx.message.delete()

                await msg.reaction.clear()

                msg1 = await msg.edit("Hewwo")

                await msg1.add_reaction("⬅️")

                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)

                if reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
                        
                    await msg.edit("Eh idk just react")
                    return

            elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
                await ctx.send("AAA")

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send("Timed out")

    @helpreee.error
    async def helpreee_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(error)
        print(error)
        raise error

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Helptest(client))
```

but it didn't work, I get an error.

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 607, in _load_from_module_spec
> spec.loader.exec_module(lib)   File "", line 779, in exec_module   File
> "", line 916, in get_code   File
> "", line 846, in source_to_code
> File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Waifu Bot\cogs\testhelp.py", line 22
> try:
> ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 312, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Waifu Bot\setup.py", line 95, in on_ready
> raise e   File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Code\Waifu Bot\setup.py", line 92, in on_ready
> client.load_extension(cog)   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 664, in load_extension
> self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)   File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 610, in _load_from_module_spec
> raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.testhelp'
> raised an error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer
> indentation level (testhelp.py, line 22)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple indentation error (at `try...except`):

```py
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

class Helptest(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def helpreee(self, ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        msg = await ctx.send("Eh idk just react")
        await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
        await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ['⬅️', '➡️']

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
            if reaction.emoji == '➡️':
                await ctx.message.delete()
                await msg.reaction.clear()
                msg1 = await msg.edit("Hewwo")
                await msg1.add_reaction("⬅️")
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=5, check=check)
                if reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
                    await msg.edit("Eh idk just react")
                    return
            elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️':
                await ctx.send("AAA")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError: #Indent error here, delete one tabulation
            await ctx.send("Timed out") #Also Delete one tabulation here

    @helpreee.error
    async def helpreee_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(error)
        print(error)
        raise error

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Helptest(client))
```

PS: To avoid indent error, avoid to skip a line after a code line, it will be easier to detect those errors and your code will be more understandable ^^

Comment: it runs, but it ignores reaction adds